# trouble with writing word to end of line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file

i can paste a new line into file,

```
   string filePath = @"C:\Users\user\Documents\1.txt";
   string tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(tempPath)))
    {
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(line);
            if (line.StartsWith("google"))
                writer.Write("StackOverflow");
        }
    }
    File.Delete(filePath);
    File.Move(tempPath, filePath);
```

How can I write at end of the line? Maybe I need to parse the line, and put my word into line.length -position?

Comment: so when you are at the end of the File in this line
`foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filePath)){}` why not just write a line when you are within the `using` but outside of the `foreach` loop?? as well as looking at `Habib's` solution which is even better.. also please step thru the code it's obvious that you are just running it and checking the end results you could have spotted this easily by debugging in all due respect

Comment: i do not understand, what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writer.WriteLine(line);` will append end of line character (`\r\n`), you need to append your string after checking if the condition is met, and later use `WriteLine` like:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
{
   if (line.StartsWith("google"))
   {
        writer.WriteLine(line + "StackOverflow");
   }
   else
   {
        writer.WriteLine(line);          
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate what you want to the end of the line.

```
writer.WriteLine(line + " Add this to the end of the line");
```